# How to call a function from another .c file

Tags: c

I wrote a program that in the main function calls a function from another .c file, but outputs an error
undefined reference to 'function_name'. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. 
I compile the program on the Linux command line: gcc -o main.exe main.c
                                                 ./main.exe

funcs.h

```
#ifndef FUNCS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCS_H_INCLUDED

int foo();

#endif
```

second.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"

int foo(){
  printf("Hello, world!");

return 0;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funcs.h"

int foo();

int main(){
  foo();

  return 0;
}
```

how to fix the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compile all c files, not only main.c

```
gcc -o main.exe main.c second.c
```

Comment: `funcs.c` -> `second.c`

Comment: @FiddlingBits Fixed, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The undefined reference is raised when no symbol is detected for specific function.

In this case it can be fixed compiling also the .c file that contains the function so :

```
gcc -o main.exe main.c second.c
```

In this way you will have the symbol for the function you call that is in funcs.c file.

Comment: `funcs.c` -> `second.c`